# After plotting a few statistics in ggplot2 my legend dissapears

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a problem with the legend in ggplot2.
after plotting my data legend disappears.
I plot three statistics: hist and two lines.
I tried to put "fill" also used "scale_fill_identity" and "scale_fill_manual" but it still is hidden.

```
    #set seed
seed=12345
#inputs
lambda = .2
n=40
sim = 1000
#simulation
sim1 <- NULL
for (i in 1:sim) sim1 = c(sim1, mean(rexp(n, lambda)))

library(ggplot2)
mydata <- as.data.frame(sim1)
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = mydata[,1])) +
geom_histogram(fill = "green", color = "blue", binwidth = .05) +
geom_vline(xintercept = mean(mydata$sim1), col = "red", size = 1.5) +
geom_vline(xintercept = 1/lambda, col = "black", size = 1.5) +
theme_light()+
labs(title="Exponential means distribution" 
     ,subtitle = "Theoretical mean vs. Sample mean"
     ,x = "exp means"
     ,y = "frequency"
     )
```

[image: as a result, I have:]

Comment: I don't see anything that would generate a legend. What do you mean by saying it "disappears"? The two lines are not generated from data so they don't require a legend.

Comment: I've updated context, I tried to put "fill" into aes() also used "scale_fill_identity" and "scale_fill_manual" but it still is hidden.

Comment: I don't think anything is "hidden". I think it was never there. At least I've been unable to see one with partial running of your code.

Comment: What should the legend contain?

Comment: I need "green" = "exp means", "red"="sample mean", "black"="theoretical mean"

Comment: @42 what should I add to create the legend?

Comment: Your mapped aesthetics (e.g. `fill`) need to be within `aes`.

Comment: what arguments "fill" must take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hell-bent of putting the up a legend, here's something that should get you started

```
seed <- 12345
lambda <- 0.2
n <- 40
sim <- 1000
sim1 <- replicate(sim, {
  mean(rexp(n, lambda))
})

library(ggplot2)
mydata <- as.data.frame(sim1)

mystats <- data.frame(stat = c("mean", "lambda"),
                      value = c(mean(mydata$sim1), 1/lambda))

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = sim1)) +
  theme_light() +
  geom_histogram(fill = "green", color = "blue", binwidth = .05) +
  geom_vline(data = mystats, aes(xintercept = value, color = stat))
```

Comment: If you add a pseudo line called 'exp means' it will also occur in the legend. You just have to match colors somehow: `mystats <- data.frame(stat = c("mean", "lambda", "exp means" ),
                      value = c(mean(mydata$sim1), 1/lambda, Inf)) `

Comment: Linus, I tried yours one it adds new line to the plot. I think means in leged quite enough. Anyway thank you guys!